# Isotope Filter and Animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am currently working on a website white implements metafizzy's isotope to sort through different image blocks which have  elements on top of them.

I've searched numerous forums and read through many stack overflow pages regarding this topic but no answer has seemed to work for me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-plugin/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.settings.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="filtersDisplay" style="background-color:rgba(158,162,162,.5);">
                                <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="Search by keyword">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</a>
                                 <ul class="filter-list" data-filter-group="subject">
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-filter=".even">Even</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-filter=".odd">Odd</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" data-filter=".prime">Prime</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-9" id="programsDisplay">
                                <section class="programsContent">
                                    <article class="program odd">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accounting1">
                                                <span class="icons">1</span>

                                            </figure>
                                        </a>
                                    </article>
                                   <article class="program even prime">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accounting2">
                                                <span class="icons">2</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program odd prime">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accounting3">
                                                <span class="icons">3</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program even">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">4</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program odd prime">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">5</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program even">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">6</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program odd prime">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">7</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program even">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">8</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program odd">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">9</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="program even">
                                        <a href="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg">
                                            <figure>
                                                <img class="programIcon" src="images/Programs/Accounting.jpg" alt="Accoutning4">
                                                <span class="icons">10</span>

                                            </figure>
                                            </a>
                                    </article>
                           </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>                              
                </div>

                </section>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<!-- isotope -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/neko-contact-ajax-plugin/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/neko-contact-ajax-plugin/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/neko-share-urls/generator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/parallax/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

I initially thought it could have been that I have put scripts in two different parts of the code but I moved the scripts at the top to the bottom and got no luck.

Here is my JS:

```
var $programs = $($container).isotope({

itemSelector: '.programs',
layoutMode: 'masonry'

});
$programs.imagesLoaded( function(){

$programs.isotope('layout');
});

$('.filter-list a').on('click', 'btn', function() {
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
$('.programsContent').isotope({
itemSelector: '.programs',
layoutMode: 'masonry',
fitRows: {
fitWidth: true
}
});
```

The responsiveness works, but the filtering and animation does not. 
Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue? I've beaten this problem dry and can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: In its current form, your question is not useful to future readers. Unless you can format it so that it presents a repeatable programming request others might benefit from as well, your questions is off-topic on this website. In its current form, your question is a job you don't know how to complete and are therefore asking others to complete for you, free of charge. Besides, you're supposed to give more specific information than *"it doesn't work"*. Are there any errors in the console? Have you tried debugging it yourself? Please set up a [mcve] using the snippet button (`<>`).

Comment: Hi Andrei, many apologies on asking the question in the way I did. My intention is not to ask others to complete code for me, I am just merely stuck and cannot seem to figure out the direction to go in. There are no errors in the console, and I have tried debugging it myself, but all my solutions have not yielded the results I was looking for. 

The links I created are supposed to reorganize my <article> elements, yet when I click on the button to do so, this does not happen. Would you happen to know if isotope.js conflicts with bootstrap in anyway that would make the isotope not work?

Comment: No, they do not conflict. Do you think you could reproduce your problem in a snippet by linking each of the resources and placing each code part in its panel, making sure the problem is reproduced? Try to keep your example minimal. Anyone answering your question will need this example to test and it's a form of respect for their time to put it together yourself. As of now the contents of your resources are unknown. Some are libraries, but others are custom scripts. We can't debug without all the elements.

Comment: I also noticed you're loading some scripts more than once. For example, `js/custom.js` is loaded in both header and footer. This is usually a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't declared your variable `$container` and second, you are using the **masonry** layout but adding in **fitRows** with it, which will not work. You haven't loaded *imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js* (it goes before isotope) and you have your isotope class as `.programs` but it is `.program`

Here is some edited code:

```
var $programs = $('.programsContent');

$programs.imagesLoaded( function(){
$programs.isotope({
itemSelector: '.program',
layoutMode: 'masonry',
});
});
```

Your filter code is incorrect as well. Your calling a click on `btn`, not the class `.btn`. Try this:

```
$('ul.filter-list li').on('click', 'a.btn', function() {
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$programs.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes you suggested, yet it still does not work. Do you happen to know if any of the isotope scripts conflict with bootstrap scripts?

Comment: What version of isotope are you using? Also, if you have a link, it would help. You have other js scripts loading which may interfere. `custom.js` loads 2x BTW

Comment: See my edits for fixed filter code. Also, I had a typo in my code (had the word isotop, not isotope). If you copied and pasted my code into your code, it would fail with isotop!